# Bootstrap carousel-control disappears on hover

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, carousel

Bootstrap carousel-control disappears on hover.
could anyone please help me out !
heres the link.

http://hg01.ispghosting.com/techashram/UIDev_Inhouse_2014/Vivekraj_KR/Html5/BibAndTucker/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because of you style.css following code snippets

```
.nav>li>a:active a:after,a:hover {
background: none !important;
border-color: transparent !important;}
```

With out source cant't give exact solution. So just comment above code snippets or just remove ",.a:hover" and check your carousel-control hover issue fix or not.

Comment: .nav>li>a:active,
.nav>li>a:hover {
 background: none !important;
 border-color: transparent !important;
}   it works. thanx !